# Python command line import of environment variable required before module import

Tags: python

I use a module that has a default location to save files:

```
import foo # default directory is used to save files
```

The module allows the use of an *environment variable* to change this location:

```
import os
os.environ['foo_path'] = "my/dir/path"
import foo # files now save in my/dir/path
```

If I import the module first, however, changing the environment variable does not help:

```
import os
import foo
os.environ['foo_path'] = "my/dir/path" #No effect, files saved in default location
```

**My problem is the following**: 
I want to be able to run my module via command line, and I want to allow the user to pass a path to set `os.environ['foo_path']`.

I am using the `click` module to pass some arguments, and thought about using it to get the path from the command line. Ignoring the other arguments, this looks like this:

```
import click
import os

@click.command()
@click.option('--foo_path', default=None, help='dirpath to use instead of default', type=str)
def import_foo(foo_path):
    if foo_path:
        os.environ['foo_path'] = "my/dir/path" #Correctly changes the dirpath 
    import foo
```

This *works*, though the import in a function is a bit annoying.

However, if `foo` is somehow imported before, the approach does not work. Imagine I need to import another module `bar` that also imports `foo`:

```
import click
import bar # which imports foo
import os

@click.command()
@click.option('--foo_path', default=None, help='dirpath to use instead of default', type=str)
def import_foo(foo_path):
    if foo_path:
        os.environ['foo_path'] = "my/dir/path" #No effect, since foo already imported   
    import foo # not executed, since foo already imported by bar
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for passing environment required in module imports?

Comment: Why use an environment variable for this?

Comment: Typically, you use whatever facilities your execution environment provides for setting environment variables. For instance, from a POSIX shell you can run `foo_path=/my/dir/path python script.py`.

Comment: @AMC not my choice, that is how the imported module works.

Comment: @chepner this works, thanks

Comment: @chepner do you want to provide an answer so I can accept? If not, I'll answer myself in Q&A style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment in which you execute your script usually provides a way to set the value of an environment variable. For example, from the POSIX shell, you can simply prefix your Python command with an assignment that only applies to the new process's environment, rather than the current shell environment:

```
foo_path=/my/dir/path python script.py
```

If you plan on running the script multiple times, you can export the variable, so that each run inherits the value from the shell.

```
export foo_path=/my/dir/path
# Each of the following will see foo_path in its environment.
python script.py
python script.py
python script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to save the location as an environment variable? Could you instead use sys.argv?

## Test.py:

```
import sys

target_fp = sys.argv[1]
print('target_fp: ', target_fp)
```

## Bash

```
python test.py 'example/path/to/file'
# ('target_fp: ', 'example/path/to/file')
```

Comment: The location needs to be saved as an environment variable because that is how the module I am importing works - it reuses this location in many places. You suggestion would actually work quite nicely, except I failed to mention that I need to use clink to pass other arguments. If I use click to pass another argument other_arg like this  python test.py 'example/path/to/file' --other_arg=some_value`, the path is identified by click as an extra argument, raising an Error